# Tabs in PHP Application - Fusion Charts

Tags: javascript, php, css

How can i display please wait or progress wheel while tab content is loading .

When i click on the tab "current status " it will load " dashboard_sla.php " which has fusion charts . while the chart is loading i want to display progress wheel or please wait .

Please find my code

```
<?php

if($status == AUTH_LOGGED){
    ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Dashboard</title>

<style>
#tabs{
    padding-right:20px;    /* The right most tab will be padded 20px from its right */
    margin:0px;
    float:right;        /* For right aligned tabs */
}
#tabs a{
    background:#000 url(images/left_tab.gif) top left no-repeat;    /* Background image is positioned top, left */
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left:5px;    /* Change this padding according to the size of image slices used to create tab */
    text-decoration:none;
}
#tabs a:hover{
    background:#EDCB27 url(images/selected_left_tab.gif) top left no-repeat;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#tabs a span{
    background:#000 url(images/right_tab.gif) top right no-repeat;    /* Note the position of background image */
    color:#FFF;
    padding-right:15px;
}
#tabs a:hover span{
    background:#EDCB27 url(images/selected_right_tab.gif) top right no-repeat;
    color:#000;
}
#tabs li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding-left:3px;
}
#tabs b{
    background:#EDCB27 url(images/selected_left_tab.gif) top left no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#tabs b span{
    background:#EDCB27 url(images/selected_right_tab.gif) top right no-repeat;
    color:#000;
    padding-right:15px;
}
#tabs span{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#tabs a,#tabs a span,#tabs b,#tabs b span{
    display:block;        /* Set display to block, otherwise background images will not work*/
    float:left;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <?php
    $tab=$_REQUEST['tab'];
    if($tab=='') $tab='Dashboard1';
?>
    <ul id="tabs">

        <?php if($tab=='Dashboard1'){ ?>
        <li><b><span>Current Status</span></b></li>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <li><a href="?tab=Dashboard1"><span>Current Status</span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($tab=='Dashboard2'){ ?>
        <li><b><span>SLA Trend IT</span></b></li>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <li><a href="?tab=Dashboard2"><span>SLA Trend IT</span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>


    </ul>
<div style="clear:both; background-color:#FFFFFF; height:0px; overflow:hidden"></div>
    <div style="border:solid 3px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">
<?php if($tab=='Dashboard1'){
     include('dashboard_sla.php');
     } else if($tab=='Dashboard2'){
        include('dashboard_sla6.php');
     } 


}
else{
echo "<center>You must log in First</center>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td style='padding:0 0 0 28px;' valign=top>";
echo "<iframe frameborder=0 width=100% name=mainf scrolling=auto src=dashboard.php marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 style=margin:0px; padding:0px; height=600></iframe>";
echo "</td></tr></table>";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
echo "\n";
} ?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look up Ajax methods in jQuery, and look up a tutorial  on Ajax online and try posting again on S.O. if you get stuck...there's too much to suggest to accomplish what you are asking and what you have posted already.

Comment: This a duplicate post. You already posted this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673730/tabs-in-php-application

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery progress bar when you click on the tab. Add Jquery UI Plug-in.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is you can add 'Loader'.
Add Loader Image.

```
<div id="loader">
<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

After that when you click on one tab write a code,

```
$('#loader').show();
```

Comment: This solution is generic. Not according to what has been asked here.

Comment: isn't a generic solution a better one in this case from which @user3116069 can get an idea of what to do?!

Comment: Then also describe what modification needed @user3116069's approach.